# How to filter distinct/unique Records in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: listdata.svc, unique

I have a list with "Created by(person-default), Period(single line of text), Team(single line of text)...." fields. More than an entry is allowed per user.

Now,

1. I may have to find the list of unique/distinct users who submitted the entries against the given period
2. Number of users(distinct/unique) against the given period & Team.

Would that be possible with Listdata.svc? or how to achieve this?

**Update: 12-Sep-2014**

The way I could do is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = new SPSite("http://intranet-dev.local").OpenWeb())
        {
            // Create a List Object
            SPList myList = web.Lists["UniqueUsers"];

            // Create a Query Object
            SPQuery curQry = new SPQuery();
            //Write the query (I suggest using U2U Query Bulider Tool)
            curQry.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>TestB</Value></Eq></Where>";

            if (myList != null)
            {
                //var uker = myList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>().Select(itm => GetListItemAuthorEmail(itm)).Distinct();
                var uker = myList.GetItems(curQry).Cast<SPListItem>().Select(itm => GetListItemAuthorEmail(itm)).Distinct();

                foreach (string str in uker)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    static public string GetListItemAuthorEmail(SPListItem spListItem)
    {
        string Email = string.Empty;
        var spFieldUser = spListItem.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Author") as SPFieldUser;

        if (spFieldUser != null && spListItem["Author"] != null)
        {
            var fieldValue = spFieldUser.GetFieldValue(spListItem["Author"].ToString()) as SPFieldUserValue;
            if (fieldValue != null)
            {
                var spUser = fieldValue.User;//Get the SPUser
                Email = spUser.Email;//Get the login name from SPUser
            }
        }
        return Email;
    }
```

But not sure if it can be achieved without much of load on the server.

Comment: In order to answer your question you need to provide more details about your list fields, at least field types..?

Comment: have updated the question..

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve this , and you will need to do enhancement the same .

http:///_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks?$filter=Team eq 'Team3'

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010-for-listdata-svc-part-1/

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46586/rest-service-filter-date-column

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, I would like know more on finding Unique/Distinct list of users as I am comfortable wit filtering..

Comment: http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/

Comment: These links are good ones, but I don't see how they answer this question...

Answer (score 2):

Both of these can be done with views using Group Bys.

1. Create a view called `ByPeriodPerson` and in the `Group By` section of the view definition, select `Period` first group by the column and then select `Person` for the second group by the column.  The resulting view will display a distinct set of *Periods* - when you expand each period you will have a distinct set of *Persons* - expand each person to see their rows for that Period. (see image for view definition)
   [image]
2. Same as 1.  Create a view called `ByPeriodTeam` and in the `Group By` section of the view definition, select `Period` first group by the column and then select `Team` for the second group by the column.  The resulting view will display a distinct set of *Periods* - when you expand each period you will have a distinct set of *Teams* - expand each team to see the Team rows for that Period. (see image for list view)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ODATA Distinct is not possible unfortunately:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839073/select-distinct-values-with-odata

You may be able to filter distinct values out afterwards ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this with XSLT in a DataViewWebPart, sorted by the key for which I wanted to find the unique values. *(H/T: Marc Anderson)*

You edit the default for-each select="$Rows" see line 3 (in my case the field was ClientName)

[image]

In this case, I connected THIS web part with only unique client names, to another web part showing more fields and records for the same list-- documents with a matching client name. [Hence the dvt.gencurselkey call].

Another way to go would be to export the list into an excel query and do a pivot table by those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use linq distict. This link shows how to do it in sharepoint:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660110/selecting-rows-with-distinct-column-values-using-linq

Answer (score -1):

You can get data into data table and do a distinct with group by clause.

Comment: In SharePoint you don't normally access the database directly. Can you elaborate on the answer further to explain how this would solve the OP question? Thank You!

Comment: Hey Benny,
first query list for particular date and time. you will get SplistitemCollection,Convert into C# data table.And then first do group by period.And for the second one,group by time and team and you will get distinct record.

Comment: Great! Can you update your answer with this info, and possibly add the code snippet to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Benny :i have added post here as i am not allowed to post answer.https://sharepointundefind.wordpress.com/